Aquatic being in the form of water
This movie had a crew going underwater for some kind of expedition. There they encounter an aquatic being which takes the form of water. Some time later, there is a scene involving missiles or explosives set at the bottom of the seabed to kill the being. The lead character realizes that the being is not evil, decides to sacrifice himself to stop the explosives. While there, the being takes him back to its ship and creates a breathable environment inside water walls. Also it manages to capture TV channels shown on a suspended water screen. The world or city is about to be destroyed by the being with a huge tidal wave. The hero convinces the being and the tidal wave is withdrawn. The final scene shows a huge ship emerging from the sea.
Which movie is this?

This appears to be a question of which you already knew the answer. While technically not "illegal", it is definitely frowned upon. If you find an answer to a question after you have posted a question, by all means, answer your own question. In this instance, you appear to just be asking a known to you question. Per this question on the Meta site you will see it is highly discouraged.

Oh I certainly did not know the answer. I only remembered the plot. I simply checked the movie after wbogacz gave the answer and Mark Chapman mentioned "special edition".

Sounds like the special edition of The Abyss to me.

correct, the special edition has the tidal wave and other scenes.

You clearly mean The Abyss from James Cameron.
Ed Harris plays the sacrificial lead character, and Elizabeth Mastrontonio, his estranged wife, who find they still love each other after the ordeal.
The nuke was set by Michael Beihn, who we of course know better as Kyle Reese in Terminator.

yes, the movie is The Abyss, but @Mark Chapman's answer got voted because the ending scenes were indeed from the Special Edition.
